Possibly inseparable extensions of $\mathbb{F}_p((t))$
I have a question on local fields. Some sources define a characteristic $p$ local field as of the form $k((t))$ where $k/\mathbb{F}_p$ is a finite extension. Some sources define it as a finite extension of $\mathbb{F}_p((t))$.
I agree that $k((t))$ is a finite extension of $\mathbb{F}_p((t))$. Furthermore, if $L/\mathbb{F}_p((t))$ is finite separable, then the ring of integers is a DVR (this somehow seems to require separability). Then using Hensel lifting one can embed the residue field into the fraction field and then we are ok.
I am wondering what happens if $L/\mathbb{F}_p((t))$ is finite inseparable. I agree that the norm on $ \mathbb{F}_p((t))$ extends uniquely to a norm on $L$, and the ring of integers and maximal ideal are still well-defined by this nonarch norm. However, I'm not sure if we can still Hensel Lift. Is there a way to get it is still of the form $k((t))$?

There are many equivalent definitions of a local field. More specifically, $K$ is a local field if it satisfies one of the following equivalent characterizations (we assume the valuation $|\ |$ is nonarch). I will use $A=\{x\in K \mid |x|\le 1\}$ to denote the valuation ring, $\mathfrak{m}=\{x\in K \mid |x|< 1\}$ to denote the maximal ideal:

$K$ is locally compact under the topology induced by $|\ |$.
$K$ is complete and discretely valued, with finite residue field.

To see that they are equivalent, see proposition 9.1-9.6 here
I will use definition 2. Note that the fact that it is discretely valued means that $\mathfrak{m}$ is actually a principal ideal; otherwise, for every $x\in \mathfrak{m}$, there exists $y\in \mathfrak{m}$ such that $|y| > |x|$, so $y \notin xA$.
Now we show that $K$ is nonarch local field and has positive characteristic $p$, we will prove that $K \cong k((t))$ as topological fields, where $k$ is the residue field of $K$.
Since $K$ is a local field, $k$ is a finite field. This means that the nonzero elements of $k$ are the roots of $x^{\# k-1}-1=0$. By Hensel's lemma on $f(x) = x^{\# k - 1} - 1 \in A[x]$, every solution of $\bar{f} \in \mathbb{F}_p[x]$ in $A/\mathfrak{m}$ can be lifted to an element of $A$ that is a root of $f$. It can be checked that these lifts form a field of $\# k$ elements, so we have an embedding $k \hookrightarrow K$. Now let $\pi$ be a uniformizer. It's clear that $A = k[[\pi]]$ and $K = k((\pi))$.
